# AVAudioPlayer noises, irreptions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I have seen a lot questions about AVAudioPlayer, but I haven't found answer to my question.
First I describe my problem
I have one class

```
@interface Ex_1: UIView {
   AVAudioPlayer *player;
}

@property(retain, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;

-(void) playSongByParameters;
@end

@implementation Ex_1
@synthesize player;

-(void) playSongByParameters {
    //here i download mp3 from url and then i get NSData *data
    //then
    NSError *err;
    if (player) {
         [player stop];
         [player release];
    }
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData : data : &err];
    if (!err) {
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
    }
}
@end
```

So in main class I create object of Ex_1 class and sometimes I call playSongByParameters method. Sometimes song plays completely and it's ok, but sometimes same song is playing during 30( maybe less, maybe more ) seconds and then it slows and then noises  appear and then it interrupted.
Onetime I stop program with breakpoint(when its problem appears) and then i continue running program and song plays completely without bugs, noises.
Can you tell me what is problem ? (I use non arc)

Comment: Are you sure that your audio file isn't corrupted?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because I play with data from the one url.